Create a system of hot swap firmware update on Arduino Nano?
Is it allowed by Arduino Nano architecture, to develop a Sketch, divided into two segments:

The one, that accepts through a CAN-bus a the new version of the firmware itself and writes it into the second segment. The purpose of the first segment is to be only triggered, when data is being transmitted.
The firmware itself.

I imagine it looking like this:
void loop(){
  
  if (CAN.onReceive(...)){
    // first segment
  }
  else{
    // second segment
  }

}

After the transmition is complete, the sketch just runs forth with updated code. Is it possible?

The InternalStorageAVR in my ArduinoOTA library can write a binary into the upper half of a classic AVR MCU flash. The library doesn't allow to use it with Nano because of the small flash size, but it is easy to remove the check.
See the advanced OTASketchDownload example on how to use InternalStorage with your own way of downloading the update binary.
InternalStorageAVR requires a modified Optiboot bootloader with the copy_flash_pages function. A hex file with the modified bootloader is available in my_boards GitHub repository.
use of InternalStorage
  if (!InternalStorage.open(length)) {
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("There is not enough space to store the update. Can't continue with update.");
    return;
  }
  byte b;
  while (length > 0) {
    if (!client.readBytes(&b, 1)) // reading a byte with timeout
      break;
    InternalStorage.write(b);
    length--;
  }
  InternalStorage.close();
  
  if (length > 0) {
    Serial.print("Timeout downloading update file at ");
    Serial.print(length);
    Serial.println(" bytes. Can't continue with update.");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Sketch update apply and reset.");
  Serial.flush();
  InternalStorage.apply(); // this doesn't return


yes, it is mentioned in the Answer. in ArduinoOTA.h and in InternalStorageAVR.cpp there is a #if FLASHEND >= 0xFFFF

Juraj, when I'm trying to run your OTASketchDownload example, the output is "error: 'InternalStorage' was not declared in this scope. note: suggested alternative: 'ExternalOTAStorage'" Could you suggest, how I can fix it?

Juraj, can you please specify, where InternalStorage puts the saved bytes and how can I read them back? I went through what documentation I've found, but still don't grasp it.

just use apply() and it will with the help of the bootloader copy it to address 0 and reset the MCU. you can't do anything else with it.

let's say I want to test it locally - in what format should I feed it the new version of the sketch?

bin format. copy platform.local.txt from library's extras/avr folder, next to platform.txt in the boards package. restart the IDE. use Export binary from Sketch menu. it will put a .bin file next to .ino

It did really create the new_version.bin.ino file for me, but how can I send it to the board and get InternalStorage to read it?

the standard way for the library is to upload from IDE over a WiFi or Ethernet shield. other options are a download over a network, read from SD card, read from Serial, I2C or any other way of transport you can do in your sketch

Juraj, I understand, that it goes far away from the topic of this question, so I asked another one: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/95996/how-to-send-a-binary-file-to-a-nano-board-through-an-isp-connection-using-arduin. Would be happy, if you'd answer it.

That sounds similar in principle to some of the SD card bootloaders that I recall reading about a few years ago. These bootloaders would look for a file on SD card when triggered and then write that to flash memory.
I understand that receiving a file via CAN is different, but I expect most of the main ideas are the same. One advantage of an SD card is that the full file can be verified before writing to flash. The Nano does not have enough RAM to store the entire 32kB, so I expect you would have to do it 'in realtime' over CAN.
https://github.com/zevero/avr_boot is one example that supports the ATmega328P (so should be compatible with the Nano).
But in essence, what you are looking for is a customised bootloader.
